# WCF Certificate Chain, verify programmatically

Tags: c#, certificate, x509

I'm trying to use certificates programmatically, rather than using the store. I'm creating `X509Certificate2`'s with filename and password.

This works fine when I have manually added the root certificate to the Certificate Store in Trusted  People. However, I'd rather not have to do that on every deployment - I'd rather deal with it programmatically too.

When I remove the root certificate from the Certificate Store I get an exception.

Everything I have read seems to say that I have to manually added the root certificate to the Certificate Store, or the Trust Chain won't work.

Question: Is there a programmatic way to set up the Trust Chain, so I don't have to do it manually?

The code looks like:

```
        var serverCert = new X509Certificate2("FullPathToMyCertificate.cer", "Password");
        Client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = serverCert;
```

The exception, which occures when I try to use the Client, is:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException 

The X.509 certificate CN=notrealcertname, OU=TPA, OU=BMP, OU=Projects, O=Somebody, C=US is not in the trusted people store. 
The X.509 certificate CN=notrealcertname, OU=TPA, OU=BMP, OU=Projects, O=Somebody, C=US chain building failed. 
The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. 
Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. 
A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The used component verifies the chain by default - when the chain can't be verified you get that exception.
IF you want to do everything including verification of the chain in code then you need to [implement "custom validation" and integrate that into the WCF Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx):

```
Client.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
              X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
Client.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
    new MyCertificateValidator();
```

Another option would be to disable validation altogether (**NOT for production !!!**)

```
Client.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
              X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

**EDIT - after comment:**

For validating the chain yourself you should take a look at [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx) and [X509Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx) - to get an idea how such a chain verification could be implemented take a look at [Mono's implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Security/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs.htm) of the `Verify`... basically you use the `Find` method to search a [X509Certificate2Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.aspx) for the parent and so on... verification criteria with a custom validation is up to you (valid signature, not expired...).

some reference links at MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509servicecertificateauthentication.certificatevalidationmode.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response, Yahia. So, then, lets say I wanted to implement a **CustomCertificateValidator** that mimicked the default behaviour that occurs when I don't use a **CustomCertificateValidator** but have manually added the root certificate to the Certificate Store in Trusted People. What would I put in my **CustomCertificateValidator**? Presumably the default behaviour evaluates the **serverCert** against the root cert in Trusted People, decides its OK, and lets the client receive the response. What does it do to make this evaluation? Thanks again, Steve.

Comment: what does client refer to here (say in Client.ServiceCertificate.), naespace please? Many Thanks.

Comment: This is NOT a namespace. This code assumes that it lies in a class derived from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<> and this "ClientBase" exposes, saying simply, a 'ClientCredentials' property on which you can do '.ServiceCertificate' then '.Authentication' then '.CertificateValidationMode" and so on. If you need to know exactly, the ServiceCertificate is a class X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential